# Cassandra - replacing a non-dead node

Tags: cassandra

We are looking at a way at performing a rolling upgrade of a Cassandra cluster within our CI environment.

We have Cassandra running across a number of VMs.  When a VM is spun up it is allocated a random IP address from a pool.  We cannot control this to get a static IP address.  We also are "not allowed" to login to a VM to run a manual upgrade of Cassandra.  So to upgrade, we need to spin up a new VM and install the later version of Cassandra on it.

Ideally, we'd like to:

- Shutdown Cassandra on an existing node;
- Spin up a new node with a new version of cassandra and a new IP address;
- copy the data from the old node to the new node;
- start up the new node, as it's it was the old node (autobootstrap=false);

  - some Cassandra setting would likely be needed here to tell the cluster that this is an existing node, along the lines of cassandra.replace_node but that doesn't require autobootstrap=true)
- run "nodetool upgradesstables".

We've thought about using cassandra.replace_node or cassandra.replace_node_first_boot, but documentation on these strongly implies (or states) that the node has to be bootstrapped when using these, meaning we can't copy the data from the old node (as it would be ignored/overwritten/duplicated).

Is it possible to do what we want to do without having to bootstrap the node?

(We are looking at the possibility of static IP addresses - if we can reuse the IP address, then the node would appear as a node being upgraded - no bootstrap necessary.  However, it's not looking likely that we can have static IPs).

Comment: It isn't a good idea to add nodes rather than upgrading the existing ones. The entire data has to be re-streamed and whenever an existing node is being decommissioned they start shedding their data as well. So there will be lot of data streaming instead of just upgrading the existing binary.

Comment: Why not just stop Cassandra and upgrade? Can create a new image for any new instances that startup. It will be a good exercise since you need to have processes and such setup to do things like restarts and upgrades for situations like critical bugs or you can end up in a really bad place in the future.

Comment: I'd be happy to just stop C* and upgrade, but we're not allowed to do it that way.  All upgrades must be on new VMs, in accordance with the new policies on the CI platform. My hands are tied.

When the new VM comes up, the old VM is still available, so the data is available.  So I'm looking for a way to copy the data from that old VM to the new, do to C* magic, and have that new node come up as the old node, just with a new IP address.

I suppose a similar question would be: How do I change the IP address of a node in my C* cluster?  If we can answer that, we can answer the scenario above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone else has already done this:

http://engineering.mydrivesolutions.com/posts/cassandra_nodes_replacement/

We'll try this out and see how well it works for us.